# Error - ORA00918: Column ambiguously defined PLSQL-PIVOT

Tags: plsql, pivot

The outcome is,

PartNo InventorySiteCCC PurchaseSiteCCC Supplier_PurchaseSiteCCC
XXX             1           1                      1

My query looks like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT A.part_no,  I.contract, I.part_no,  
       P.contract, P.part_no, SP.contract, SP.part_no, SP.vendor_no 
FROM PART_CATEGORY A
LEFT JOIN INVENTORY_PART I ON I.part_no = A.part_no 
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_PART P ON P.part_no = A.part_no 
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_PART_SUPPLIER SP ON SP.part_no = A.part_no AND (SP.vendor_no IS NOT NULL AND SP.PRIMARY_VENDOR_DB = 'Y')
ORDER BY A.part_no
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(I.contract) AS Inventory, 
  COUNT(P.contract) AS Purchase,
  COUNT(SP.contract) AS Supplier_Purchase  
  FOR (contract) IN ('CCC' AS SiteCCC, 'SSS' AS SiteSSS)
)[enter image description here][1]
ORDER BY A.part_no;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised because you have four columns named the same.

Columns: `SP.part_no`,`A.part_no`, `I.part_no` and `P.part_no` will have same column name resulting in column name: `part_no`.

If you give different aliases to these columns the problem should disappear.

The same goes for contract column.

Your query after correction could look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT A.part_no as part_no_a,  
       I.contract as contract_i, 
       I.part_no as part_no_i,  
       P.contract as contract_p, 
       P.part_no as part_no_p, 
       SP.contract as contact_sp, 
       SP.part_no as part_no_sp, 
       SP.vendor_no 
FROM PART_CATEGORY A
LEFT JOIN INVENTORY_PART I ON I.part_no = A.part_no 
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_PART P ON P.part_no = A.part_no 
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_PART_SUPPLIER SP ON SP.part_no = A.part_no AND (SP.vendor_no IS NOT NULL AND SP.PRIMARY_VENDOR_DB = 'Y')
ORDER BY A.part_no
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(contract_i) AS Inventory, 
  COUNT(contract_p) AS Purchase,
  COUNT(contract_sp) AS Supplier_Purchase  
  FOR (put_here_correct_contract_column) IN ('CCC' AS SiteCCC, 'SSS' AS SiteSSS)
)[enter image description here][1]
ORDER BY A.part_no;
```

Comment: @Keshani I can see that you are new on stackoverflow. If answer is correct and solved your case, you should accept this answer. There is a button for it at the left top corner of an answer.